# what does the multiplication of Quantum state represent?

Tags: quantum-state, entanglement

According to my understanding of QC/QM:

1. A **matrix** is a function/operation which when applied on vectors, changes/rotates them.
2. Ket and bra notation is used to denote quantum state.

Question 1:
`<0|0> gives scalar`

when bra zero and ket zero are multiplied we get a scalar. I understood this numerically but what exactly is this scalar? what does it represent?

Question 2: `|0><0| gives matrix`

when ket zero and bra zero is multiplied we get a matrix, I understood it numerically but what exactly this matrix represent?

Bonus Question:

since bra and ket represent quantum states so multiplying two quantum states give a scalar or matrix. what does it mean to multiply quantum states? why do we multiply quantum states? Like multiplying a scalar with vector SCALES the vector, here role of multiplication is easy to get.

Comment: each post should contain a single, laser-focused question. Please feel free to edit the post accordingly. You can ask different questions on different posts

Comment: @gIS, okay I will do that

Comment: @TristanNemoz, thanks for input, I couldn't understand at my first reading of suggested link but now it seems similar, please mark duplicate.